# Who would want to control a weather controlling device?

Tags: magic, science-fiction

I have a town that is focused around a device from a lost civilization, the current civilization an the people of this city know how to use the device to control the weather but they don't know why it was built, or what the history of it is.

So far the people who are in control of it are clerics of a storm god and they use this device mostly for the good of the people, but they do accept bribes and such to change the weather to favor whoever the highest bidder is, as long as it doesn't bring destruction.

My question is who as a faction or person/people would want to take over this device and why, what could they use it for?

The game setting is D&D 5e although it's mixed with aspects of the Numenera game, hence the device.

The device is actually a giant eyeball made of unknown materials and whenever certain substances are placed onto the eye it will create the appropriate weather.
EX: water placed on the eye will bring rain. sand=sand storm, covering the eye=darkness blood=blood rain, poison/acid= acid rain etc.

The weather effect covers only the town and surrounding fields, and it can not be used to target a specific area. It can control temperature and wind as well.  If you choose to blow on it with a certain force, or cast lightning spells at it.

Comment: What is the range of the weather effect and can the eye be targeted on a specific area?

Comment: Define `as long as it doesnt[sic] bring destruction`. Would a drought that kills the harvests and brings a famine, but does not damage directly anyone, "bring destruction"?

Comment: Who would want it? Uh, everyone. Problem I see is that there are a lot more options that are not benevolent. You say it doesn't involve destruction, but...the options are there. Also, it's focused only on rain--there's nothing to adjust intensity, wind, or temperature? How about area? Is it a specific area around the eye? Can that be expanded or made pin pointed?

Comment: The weather effect covers only the town and surrounding fields, and it can not be used to target a specific area.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add, yes it can control temperature and wind as well.if you choose to blow on it with a certain force, or cast lightning spells at it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because story based; seeking for plot

Answer (score 3):

1. Use of weather eye to send storms and tornadoes against enemies - ho hum.  Been done.
2. Use of weather eye to modify land / terraform - bah.
3. Use of weather eye to make pretty rainbows - sure.

   4. **Use of weather eye by renegade giant otters who want to go sledding - yeah!**

Giant otters are an excellent and much underused monster from the original monster manual.  They are rowdy, clever and smart.  Everyone knows otters love to go sledding.  Your renegade giant otters steal the eye and make it snow.  And then: they go sledding!

In between sledding sessions, the giant otters will mercilessly and repeatedly prank the players who are coming to retrieve the weather eye.

[image]

Comment: Unlikely regular otters, which are adorable, giant otters are also [scary](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Giant_otter_2.JPG/170px-Giant_otter_2.JPG) as [hell](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/1920x1080/p014rt82.jpg).